# sql only return 1 record from the stored proc with php

Tags: php

I have the following code in php which using to run the stored proc to return the records from the database.

```
public function MelHpdlSql02($database)
{
    $connection = mssql_connect("SQL-02", "user", "test");
    $db = mssql_select_db($database);
    return $connection;
}

public function getRoleRecords()
{
    $this->MelHpdlSql02("Staff");

    $version = mssql_query("EXEC app_role_select");
    $row = mssql_fetch_array($version);     


    var_dump($row);die;

}
```

This is only return me the 1 record from the database (which this suppose to have 10 records return when I'm manually running the stored proc)

Does anyone know what is going wrong with my code?

Comment: this is because you only `fetch` result wich will give you only first row, you need to loop throw result by doing a `while` before fetching.

Comment: where is your stored procedure code?

Comment: i explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is mistake in your code please check the below code.

```
public function MelHpdlSql02($database)
    {
        $connection = mssql_connect("SQL-02", "user", "test");
        $db = mssql_select_db($database);
        return $connection;
    }

public function getRoleRecords()
{
    $this->MelHpdlSql02("Staff");

    $version = mssql_query("EXEC app_role_select");
    while($row = mssql_fetch_array($version))
    {
         var_dump($row);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i meant, when you use your function:

```
public function getRoleRecords()
{
   $this->MelHpdlSql02("Staff");

   $version = mssql_query("EXEC app_role_select");
   $row = mssql_fetch_array($version);     


   var_dump($row);die;

}
```

you are only fetching first result you need to loop in there something like:

```
public function getRoleRecords()
{
   $this->MelHpdlSql02("Staff");

   $version = mssql_query("EXEC app_role_select");
   while($row = mssql_fetch_array($version))     
   {
        // do anything while looping among values  
   }

}
```